# How do I know at which part of the code a spark process hangs?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Spark process that hangs - seemingly forever - in a given stage:

```
[Stage 18:>                                                         (0 + 1) / 1]
```

How can I figure out what "Stage 18" is? I tried to explain the physical plan, but I don't see a connection to the different stages.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way will be to check your Spark application UI on port 4040 by default.

You will be able to see the execution plans on stages, among other things.

[image: spark application ui]